# Android - Google Maps возвращает местонахождение null

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Мне нужно, чтобы каждые 0.1 секунд программа мне показала координаты моего местоположения в логах.

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
final Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            final Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
            Log.d("Coordinates: ", location.getLongitude() + "," + location.getLatitude());
        }
    }, 100 * i);
```

Через эмулятор программа запускается, в логах появляются координаты, но когда включаю через телефон, программа вылетает в строке, где логи, с такой ошибкой:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLongitude()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: в документации сказано следующее - `If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.`

Comment: Как это можно исправить?

Comment: ну как минимум включив определение местоположения и соответствующий провайдер

Comment: В телефоне включено определение местоположения. Речь идет об интернет провайдере?

Comment: провайдером координат могут выступать: вышки сотового оператора, wifi, gps...